# Which programming language first came up with the finally block?

Tags: programming-languages, history, finally

**Which programming language first came up with the finally block?**

I ask purely out of curiosity.

It is a very useful piece of [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar), and whoever first created it surely has a very impressive grasp of solutions to programming problems.

(Note: it is deceptively difficult to find an answer to this question...)

Comment: Why would you call it syntactic sugar?

Comment: Related reading: [Why is there no 'finally' construct in C++?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/197562/22815)

Comment: @PieterB the block helps avoid duplicate code (copy pasting the statement into try and each catch block). A try-finally block helps avoid a try-catch-rethrow block which is ugly, harder to understand, and defeats the purpose of such blocks. To quote [another source](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=32100), everything _can_ be accomplished without the finally block, but everything also _can_ be accomplished on a Turing Machine. That doesn't make it good form, though.

Comment: @patstuart Hmm... C is just syntactic sugar for a turing machine?

Comment: @MichaelT: I thought C was syntactic sugar for assembly. ;)

Comment: @PieterB because you can replace try{}finally{...} with `try{}catch(e){...;throw e;}`

Comment: @ratchetfreak It's not that simple. `...` is also executed when the `try` block is left via any other means: `continue`, `break`, `return`, and whatever other control flow statements the language offers. Of course there is still a way to replace the `finally` with other constructs but I think it's far beyond the threshold for syntactic sugar.

Comment: @ratchetfreak: In the .NET framework, it is possible in VB.NET and probably other languages as well for a Try block to specify code which, if an exception is thrown which is not handled by any inner Try block, should run before inner `finally` methods.  Catching and immediately rethrowing an exception is thus not the same thing as not catching it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to wikipedia the first to introduce this was NIL.

[The cleanup behavior now generally called "finally" was introduced in NIL (New Implementation of LISP) in the mid- to late-1970s as UNWIND-PROTECT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling#History).